# Custom Action Control Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, custom-controls, rating

I have created a custom rating control using Apples's documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html. I have been able to successfully add it to another view. I am now trying to get an action event, say a value change of the rating action event, in the new view where i have added this custom control. How can we do this ?

I tried to use the `endTrackingWithTouch` and then later calling `valueChanged` in the new view where i have placed this rating  but could not get it working.

```
override func endTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // return the rating here . ?
}
```

What i essentially am hoping to do is that, in the new view controller where i have placed this rating contol, i have a method which keeps track of changing rating values. Would appreciate any pointers . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I was able to figure it out by following this tutorial. It's not a star rating control, but it's a control that uses a UIStackView.

https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-create-a-custom-control-using-a-bitmask/

The way the Apple tutorial creates a custom control is kind of wrong surprisingly. The Apple tutorial tells you to inherit from UIStackView. Instead, you need to inherit from UIControl, create a UIStackView, then add the UIStackView instance as a subview.

To be able to call IBActions, you would add sendActions(for: .valueChanged) in the appropriate places within RatingControl.

You should then be able to control + click and drag from your storyboard to your code like you would any other control, then choose the Value Changed action for your IBAction.